# How to install apxs on xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, mod-wsgi

I have a site I'm running off an Apache server, and I want to run a python script using the server and the web browser. I'm using xampp, and I have researched that I have to use [modwsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/), and I have downloaded the zip and unpacked it onto my desktop. Now using command prompt I run

```
setup.py install
```

The first time I did this, I didn't have setup tools installed for python (I have python 2.7.8 and I'm on Windows 7 64 bit), so I went ahead and downloaded that, but now when I run the command again I get the following message

```
RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears to not to be installed or is not exectuable.
Please check the list of prerequistes in the documentation for the package and install 
any missing Apache httpd server packages.
```

How exactly do I install apxs because I don't have Apache but xampp?

Answer (score 4):

I was installing `apxs` on XAMPP in Windows. I wrote [a blog post](http://lcasoft.es/?p=150) with the complete solution (in Spanish). I basically compiled my own version of apxs. The steps were:

- Install ActiveState Perl for Windows
- Add `C:\xampp\apache\bin` to the environment variable `Path`
- Download apxs from [here](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/additional/)
- Unzip tar.gz file in `C:\xampp\apache\bin`.
- Execute:

> ppm install dmake
>
> cd c:\xampp\apache\bin\apxs
>
> perl Configure.pl --with-apache2=C:\xampp\apache
>   --with-apache-prog=httpd.exe

Comment: `ppm install dmake` gives "Could not locate a PPD file for package dmake"

Comment: and `perl Configure.pl --with-apache2=C:\xampp\apache --with-apache-prog=httpd.exe` gives `Can't locate util.pl in @INC (@INC contains: C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/site/lib C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/vendor/lib C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/lib) at Configure.pl line 10.`.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari use 'perl -I /path/to/util.pl configure.pl'. That would solve the '@INC' issue.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari this is happening because you installed Strawberry Perl and not ActiveState perl from activestate.com, just follow the steps exactly.